# Graphing polynomial functions

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

I am having problems understanding how to graph $(x^2 -1)(x^2 -9)$,

Any help would be much appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Your function crosses the $x$ axis four times. Find the zeroes of the function. Mark those points. If you were to expand it into the 4th degree polynomial that it is, it would have a positive leading coefficient, hence it would come down from the left to the first zero, then in the end come up at the last. If you were to play with a graphing calculator of some sort like [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) for a while, it would improve your intuitive skills in these matters.

Comment: First thing I would note is the symmetry about the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is factor the polynomial completely.  Here, we have $(x^{2} - 1)$ can be factored into $(x - 1)(x + 1)$ because it is a difference of squares (since it is equal to $(x^{2} - 1^{2}))$.  Similarly, $(x^{2} - 9)$ is also a difference of squares since it can be written as $(x^{2} - 3^{2})$, and so it factors into $(x - 3)(x + 3)$.

So, we have $(x^{2} - 1)(x^{2} - 9) = (x - 1)(x + 1)(x - 3)(x + 3)$.  Which values make this expression equal to 0?  These are your *roots* or *zeroes* (roots and zeroes are two words for the same concept -- the numbers where your polynomial crosses the $x$-axis).

Now draw your $x$ and $y$-axis, and label your roots.  Use test points between each of the roots to determine if the polynomial is positive or negative by plugging the test points into the polynomial.  If the test point yields a positive number, then draw your polynomial from the right root on the $x$-axis upward then downward to connect to the left-most root.  Repeat for each interval.

Answer (score 1):

If you factor $(x^2-1)$ into $(x+1)$ and $(x-1)$ and factor $(x^2-9)$ into $(x+3)$ and $(x-3)$, you can determine that the $x$-intercepts for your equation are $1, -1, 3,$ and $-3$. Unless you need to graph it exactly, using the roots to do an approximation should suffice.

Comment: If you're ever unsure of how many roots you need, remember that the roots are where your graph crosses the x-axis. You can figure out how many times it crosses the x-axis by determining the degree of the function. If you only have the roots of the function and want to determine the degree, add the degrees of those roots.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: A good place to start is to find the intercepts. Note that $(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$